# javascript window.print() not able to print complete grid

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I want to print a `gridview` control included in an `asp:Panel` control. My grid view has more than 50 columns. I am trying to print this `asp:Panel` using `window.Print() javascript` method. Also i am using a `print.css` file to print this page.
`print.css` code:

```
body, html {
   height: 100%; width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;      
}


@media print {
      body, html {
          width: 100%;height:100%
      }
}
```

`.aspx code`

```
<div >
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuery" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="690px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnExecute" runat="server" OnClick="btnExecute_Click" Text="Execute" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrintCurrentPage" runat="server" Text="Print Current Page" 
            OnClientClick="PrintGridData()" Enabled="False" />
        <div class="mainPrint" id="wrapper">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlResult" runat="server"  ScrollBars="Both" >
                <asp:GridView ID="gvResult" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                    AllowPaging ="True" PageSize="50" ForeColor="Black" 
                    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" 
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="0"
                    onrowdatabound="gvResult_RowDataBound">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

after populating the `gridview` there are 50+ columns, and after clicking to print it is printing some of columns and truncating rest of them. Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the CSS `table-layout: fixed;` to your GridView.  You can then control the column widths as desired rather than leaving it up to the browser to figure out (and get wrong). So you'll need a class, I usually do something like this:

```
.fixedLayout {
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

And then

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResult" CssClass="fixedLayout" ...>
```

You can easily apply the column widths in the code behind with the `RowCreated` event, for example:

```
protected void MyGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell dc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            switch (dc.ContainingField.ToString())
            {
                case ("Column1"):
                    dc.Width = 100;
                    dc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                    break;
                case ("Column2"):
                case ("Column3"):
                    dc.Width = 50;
                    break;
                case ("Column4"):
                    dc.Width = 215;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using `table-layout: fixed;` also has the advantage of being faster to render to the screen as the browser doesn't try calculating the cell sizes.

Comment: thank you so much  sir for the response. However, column widt are already set to optimum width and i have used the smallest `font-size` to reduce the risk of big table. I have applied your suggestion but it didn't work on this grid. I think we need to try something else to force browser to print remaining grid on next page. Hope you have understood my point thanks!

Comment: so you're just running out of space on the page to print?